# Creating arrays out of objects in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, lodash

Given the following object:

```
Object {November 2014: Object}
    November 2014: Object
        Cars: Object
            324: Object
                duration: 1417132808000
                total: "00:00:08"
                trips: 1
            369: Object
                duration: 5668531247000
                total: "00:00:47"
                trips: 4
            391: Object
                duration: 9919930257000
                total: "00:10:57"
                trips: 7
            396: Object
                duration: 9919929791000
                total: "00:03:11"
                trips: 7
            KE-22: Object
                duration: 5668531269000
                total: "00:01:09"
                trips: 4
```

I need to be able to create arrays from data extracted from it.

Something like this:

**Labels**: (Key from Objects inside Cars)
`[324, 369, 391, 396, KE-22]`

**Series**: (Properties from each object inside Cars)
`[Trips, Total]`

**Data**: (Values from properties for each object inside Cars)

```
[
    [1,4,7,7,4], // Array of trips for each car, in order.
    ["00:00:08", "00:00:47", "00:10:57", "00:03:11", "00:01:09"] // Array of total duration for each car, in order.
]
```

With this arrays I intend to **populate a chart for each month**.

The collection of objects has been created using the following code, probably is relevant to the question:

```
    var dataByMonth = _.groupBy($scope.recordlist, function(record) { 
        return moment(record.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MMMM YYYY'); 
    });

    dataByMonth = _.mapValues(dataByMonth, function(month) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.Cars = _.groupBy(month, 'car');
        obj.Drivers = _.groupBy(month, 'driver');

        _.each(obj, function(groupsValue, groupKey) {
            obj[groupKey] = _.mapValues(groupsValue, function(groupValue) {
                return _.reduce(groupValue, function(sum, trip) {
                    sum['trips']++;
                    sum['duration']+= moment.utc(trip.duration, 'HH:mm:ss');
                    sum['total'] = moment.utc(sum.duration). format('HH:mm:ss')
                    return sum;
                }, {trips: 0, duration: 0, total:0})
            });
        })

        return obj;
    });

    $scope.statistics = dataByMonth;
    console.log($scope.statistics);
```

Any tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

```js
_.chain(cars).pairs().map(function(p) {
  var id = p[0];
  return [id].concat(_.values(p[1])); // produces an array of [{id, duration, trips, total}]
}).reduce(function(acc, as) { 
  // we assume properties are sorted
  return _.map(as, function(a, i) { 
    return acc[i] = (acc[i] || []).concat([a]); 
  }); 
}, []).value();
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem with objects is that they cannot guarantee the order of their properties.

This means that before converting to arrays, you need to somehow decide on a predifined sequence algorithm. In the code below this is the alphanumeric order of the property names.

```
var objPart = obj["November 2014"]["Cars"];
var ret = _.chain(objPart).transform(function(total, n , key){
    //In this first iteration we collect all possible series that may exist,
    total.series =_.union(total.series, _.keys(n) );
    //and all labels
    total.labels.push(key);
}, {labels:[], series:[], data:[]} ).mapValues(function(val){
    //sorting labels, series. Data do not yet exist
    return _.sortBy(val);
}).value();

//based on the above orders generate a multi dimensional array for data.
ret = _.transform(ret.labels, function(total, lbl){
    var arr = _.transform(ret.series, function(partialTotal, ser){
        partialTotal.push(objPart[lbl][ser]);
    }, []);
    total.data.push(arr);
}, ret);

console.log("Labels:",ret.labels);
console.log("Series:",ret.series);
console.log("Data:",JSON.stringify(ret.data));
```

The above solution will work even for the data below:

```
var obj = {
    "November 2014": {
        "Cars": {
            "339": {
                "trips": 1,
                "total": "00:00:08",
                "duration": 1417132809000,
            },            
            "324": {
                "trips": 1,
                "extraProp1":"x",
                "total": "00:00:08",
                "duration": 1417132808000,

            },
            "369": {
                "duration": 5668531247000,
                "trips": 4,
                "total": "00:00:47",
                "extraProp2":"y"
            },
            "391": {
                "duration": 9919930257000,
                "trips": 7,
                "total": "00:10:57"
            },
            "396": {
                "duration": 9919929791000,
                "total": "00:03:11",
                "trips": 7
            },
            "KE-22": {
                "duration": 5668531269000,
                "total": "00:01:09",
                "trips": 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Labels: ["324", "339", "369", "391", "396", "KE-22"]
Series: ["duration", "extraProp1", "extraProp2", "total", "trips"]
Data: [[1417132808000,"x",null,"00:00:08",1],
[1417132808000,null,null,"00:00:08",1],
[5668531247000,null,"y","00:00:47",4],
[9919930257000,null,null,"00:10:57",7],
[9919929791000,null,null,"00:03:11",7],
[5668531269000,null,null,"00:01:09",4]]
```